# htaccess URL rewrite file/param/value format

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am writing a htaaccess rule to rewrite my below URL

```
http://example.com/edit_user.php?enc=aWQ9MQ%3D%3D
```

as
    http://example.com/edit_user/enc/aWQ9MQ%3D%3D

I tried with http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php but it gives me something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^enc/([^/]*)$ /edit_user.php?enc=$1 [L]
```

But this is fixed rule for edit_user.php file, I want a rule that would work for all files in same fashion.

Also if user types in http://example.com/edit_user/ the page should redirect to http://example.com/edit_user.php since there are no parameters.

Comment: Is `/edit_user/` a real directory?

Comment: edit_user is a file, not a directory. Its edit_user.php The file is located at server root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/enc/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?enc=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava, Works like charm!